# How to provide default values on model migration / table creation?

Tags: swift, migration, vapor

```
class Foobar: Model {}
extension Foobar: Migration {}
```

When you just create a new model and you also want to create a table in database then these two lines might be enough already.

If you want to provide more properties with primitive types like `var id: Int?` Vapor know how to handle it.

But what if you have something like this ...

```
enum FancyType: String, Codable {
    case awesome
    // ...
}
```

... and your model is expecting a default value for initialization and table creation?

```
class Foobar: Model {
    let fancy: FancyType

    init(fancy: FancyType = .awesome) {
        self.fancy = fancy
    }
}
```

In my case it just crashes with a fatal error saying:

> DecodingError: Cannot initialize Foobar from invalid String value 0

With that I'm curious how to actually configure default values on table creation.

Comment: What is the code in your `case awesome` that initialises an instance of `FancyType`? Also (but probably not relevant to your immediate problem) shouldn't `Foobar` conform to `Migration`?